# Employer monitoring outlook emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I got an inappropriate email to my work email account. I know they use filters to prevent certain things from getting in. Since this got through does that mean it passed the filters or could have still been flagged?
Basically, my husband ordered something and the confirmation and everything went to my work email. There are words in the text that should have been flagged. I don't know what will happen if it was flagged and my work finds out about it.

Comment: Unless you have a work place where IT/management paranoid.  Most rely on automated filters, and if they aren't triggered nobody cares.  Unless the email are unusually burdensome, like each has a 100mb attachment.  Many companies are required to keep emails for 5+ years, but unless management, lawyers ask for them they are ignored.  Most don't want to know if they discover something illegal it will cost them $1,000+ (if 10's of thousands) in legal and labor costs.

Answer (score 1):

No one except your IT (and possibly management) at your work can answer this question for you with any authority as all of these things are entirely dependent on the server setup.

If the email got through, it obviously got past the filters, and unless you are in a paranoid workplace you are probably OK - however this does not mean that there is no record of the email or its contents lurking somewhere.  (Some places forbid storing emails, others require it, and, of-course, it is extremely likely that, at a minimum, the the To and From addresses will be logged)

It is possible the email got flagged, but this would appear somewhat unlikely that any human being will look at it - although its not impossible.